# ffmpeg's strange behaviour-Conversion started when I close my application

Tags: c#, process, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg in my application to rotate video, but problem is that when I start conversion ffmpeg only shows it's version information and not start the actual conversion, but when I close my application ffmpeg process remains in Running Processes in Taskbar and start to convert the file.

ffmpeg output
[image]

Here is my code, please tell me where i'm doing it wrong.

```
void ConvertVideo(object[] arr) {

    string Argument = (string)arr[0];
    string OutputFolder = (string)arr[1];
    string ConvertedFile = (string)arr[2];


    UpdateStatus("Converting! Please wait...");
    ffmpeg = new Process();
    ffmpeg.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
    ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    ffmpeg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = Argument;
    ffmpeg.Start();
    myStreamReader = ffmpeg.StandardError;
    outputLine = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
    UpdateRTB(outputLine);//Write line to ritchtextbox
    do
    {
        if (outputLine.Contains("muxing overhead"))
        {
            UpdateStatus("Muxing video");
        }

        if (outputLine.StartsWith("frame"))
        {
            UpdateStatus("Converting video");
        }
    }
    while (!(ffmpeg.HasExited & (string.Compare(outputLine, "") == 0 | outputLine == null)));
    ffmpeg.Close();
    myStreamReader.Close();
    UpdateStatus("Convertion completed successfully");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're not initializing the redirection for stdout, and you're only reading from the `StandardError` stream once.  It's quite possible that you're getting a stall on the process because the stdout or stderr streams are filling with data that is not being processed.

If you wire up handlers to the `OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived` events on the `ffmpeg` process object and call `BeginOutputReadLine` and `BeginErrorReadLine` on it, you can get asynchronous output events from the process.  Use these to update your display and so on.  Wire up a handler to the `Exited` event to signal exit and you can do the whole thing asynchronously.

For synchronous conversion, try this:

```
void ConvertVideo(object[] arr) {

    string Argument = (string)arr[0];
    string OutputFolder = (string)arr[1];
    string ConvertedFile = (string)arr[2];


    UpdateStatus("Converting! Please wait...");
    using (ffmpeg = new Process())
    {
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = Argument;

        ffmpeg.OutputDataReceived += ffmpeg_OutputDataReceived;
        ffmpeg.ErrorDataReceived += ffmpeg_ErrorDataReceived;

        ffmpeg.Start();
        ffmpeg.BeginErrorReadLine();
        ffmpeg.BeginOutputReadLine();

        ffmpeg.WaitForExit();
    }

    UpdateStatus("Convertion completed successfully");
}

public void ffmpeg_OutputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // ignore data from stdout?
}

public void ffmpeg_ErrorDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    UpdateRTB(e.Data);

    if (e.Data.Contains("muxing overhead"))
        UpdateStatus("Muxing video");

    if (e.Data.StartsWith("frame"))
        UpdateStatus("Converting video");
}
```